# LTspice: unknown subcircuit error

Tags: ltspice, error

I got this error, can someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: messy schematic ... D1 and D2 are not connected to R3 ... several other components are the same way ... the zig-zag above R5 is clutter ... C7 should be above R11 ... component labels at U2 are a mess

Comment: You didn't follow directions:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGZ0U.png

Comment: how would I? I literally have no idea whati should do

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add `.lib opamp.sub` to your schematic. Press <kbd>S</kbd> and type that, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then <kbd>L-Click</kbd> to place the SPICE directive. Alternatively, use `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp1` (no need for power supplies), or `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp2` or `3, 3a, 3b` (which do need power supplies).

Additionally, you forgot to add a ground to `V1, V2`, value to `C1` (that I can see, else is obscured by the message), you don't have a junction between `D1, D2` and `D3, D4`, or `C2, C3, C4`. It looks like you're not using `U2` as you should: you're using the power pins as inputs, and the inputs just connected through `R5`. And that `LM324` is probably just the `opamp2` renamed -- if so, it won't work that way, unless you're providing some sort of a `.subckt`, which had better have 3 pins only.

I would recommend stepping back and analyzing your goals, before asking for help. Also, your schematic is a bit of a [spaghetti dish](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

Comment: i need more details, how can I add  .lib opamp.sub? it's my first time using LTSpice and I'm lost!

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi I've already told you what to do. It's quite literally the 2nd sentence in my answer. If you haven't bothered to read that far, what chances are there that you will even read the manual? (it's there precisely to help you) Which would also imply you haven't even read the part where I point out a few other mistakes... If you don't help yourself, nobody can force you. I certainly won't.

Comment: I did read it, i just don't know where should I press the S and the other things! I'm illiteracy in this, and thank you so much for your help

Comment: It means press the `S` key on your keyboard, or go to the menu in "*Edit > SPICE Directive*". @Maryam , don't get me wrong, I wish you the best with your project but, this is not the way to go. Read a guide, a tutorial, the manual (the help file, press the `F1` key) actually has this purpose, to help the users. This project is too complicated for someone doing this the first time. Learn the tool so that you'll know how to use it. Otherwise you'll have to stop at every step, ask, and wait for answers for hours or maybe days. If this is the only time you ewant to use LTspice, let someone else.

Comment: thank you so much, it's my graduation project, and my professor imposed me to use LTSpice

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi then ask your professor to help you with LTspice usage, or read/watch a few tutorials.