# LTspice in error with a battery

Tags: ltspice

I get this error from LTspice. I know the problem is in the battery, but I don't know what to do.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Where is the battery in your circuit? Fix the dangling nodes, and things will likely improve.

Comment: V1 and V2 are the batteries

Comment: how can i fix the dangling nodes?

Comment: You already got hints in [the previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642850/95619). It looks like you don't read answers so then why would anyone bother to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Your voltage sources only have one connection. You can't just leave things unconnected like that. You probably want them connected to ground.

Also U6 has no connection to the output. If that's your output try putting a resistor between it and ground, something like 1k. Check the wiring of U6, you have both inputs to it grounded so it's not going to do much of anything.

R8 is shown as 1 milliohm. If you want it to be 1 megohm you need to put 1meg not 1m.

Also, as someone said in a previous question you are using the ideal op-amp model which is probably going to give you problems. Select a model for a real op-amp and connect power to them correctly.

Lastly, label your output node so when you plot it we can see which one it is, looking at a plot that shows a signal such as V(n010) is meaningless to us as we don't know where that is on the schematic. Use the Label Net tool to name the nodes you're going to plot.

Comment: I connected the Voltage sources to GND but still the same ERROR

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi I added a bit to the answer, check this and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The error is saying that you placed a **behavioural** source (`bv`) instead of a voltage source (`voltage`), to which you attributed the wrong value: it expects `V=<expression>`, but you wrote a numeric literal, which is what the normal votage source expects. And, since you renamed the reference designator from `B` to `V`, LTspice needs to know that the element is a behavioural source, which starts with the letter `B`, and so it adds that paragraph sign you see there: `B§V...`.

The other schematic errors are already addressed in the answer to [your other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/642850/95619), though having a floating pin of the voltage source shouldn't make LTspice abort the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Place GND on negative sides of V1 and V2..They have no reference potential at the moment.

Comment: i did, and still the same ERROR

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi then do usual debugging..delete parts of your circuit until it works 